# Java не считывает дробные числа

Tags: java

Я в Java новичок и столкнулся с тем, что Java не хочет считывать с клавиатуры дробные числа. Синтаксис скопирован с интернета про то как вводить с клавиатуры числа типа  double. Но у меня сё ровно не считывает. В чём может быть  проблема?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test111 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        double i = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Код рабочий, вопрос лишь в том, как выражается ваша проблема (ошибка или просто вывод без дроби?) и как вы вводите эти числа. Обычно дробные числа пишутся через точку, с запятой могут быть проблемы.

Comment: Вообще не выводит. Как в консоли пишу дробное число то там сразу такое: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
 at Test111.main(Test111.java:8)

Comment: Вот опробовал ввести с запятой и всё вроде сразу нормально

Comment: Используйте локаль нужной культуры (страны): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323628/5045688

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, Вы используете `,`, а не `.`, но я добавил защиту, и теперь Вы можете вводить, что угодно (даже буквы (он их пропустит)), а  `,`, заменит на  `.`:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    char[] cs = scanner.nextLine().replace(',', '.').toCharArray();
    
    String allowed = "0123456789";
    boolean point = false;
    String newStr = "0";
    for (char c : cs) {
        if(allowed.indexOf(c) != -1) {
            newStr += c;
        }else if (c == '.') {
            if(point)
                break;
            newStr += '.';
            point = true;
        }
    }
    double d = Double.valueOf(newStr);
    System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: Плохой и неправильный ответ. Нужно использовать локаль нужной культуры (страны): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323628/5045688

Comment: но ведь работает, да и вряд ли автору вопроса это все еще нужно PS: у меня зато и можно ввести как `,`, так и `.`